# How to randomize UILabel text each time the view controller is showed

Tags: swift, uilabel

How do I make a label in my ViewController have a diffrent string of text each time the view crontroller is shown? Thanks! I'm using Swift 3

Comment: What did you try so far ?
Do you know how to generate random text ? Do you know where to place code for randomisation (UIViewController lifecycle) ?
Do you want random text or random text from given array ?

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski I couldn't figure it out. I seached the internet, of course, but most of the answers were in objective c. No, sorry...

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski I want random arrays such as "Hey" or "Hi" or "Hello"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you know how to add `UILabel` to your `ViewController`, here is quick sample how to pick random text on start:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let allTexts = ["Hey", "Hi", "Hello"]
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel! //get UILabel from storyboard

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.label.text = self.allTexts[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.allTexts.count)))]
    }
}
```

Adding this code to `viewWillAppear` will change your text anytime ViewController is about to appear - which means if you cover it with another ViewController (let's say popup) and then hide popup - it will change text.

If your prefer to just do it one time - when UIViewController is created put the same code inside `viewDidLoad` method.