# Change label text when pressing a button using contents from an array

Tags: arrays, swift, button, label

I'm trying to change the text of a label when pressing one of two buttons (Button 1 named "Past", button 2 named "future). The outcome should be when pressing either button 1 or button 2, it should change the label text with the content of array 1 (pastData) or array 2 (futureData).

I'm quite stuck, so I'm not sure where to start anymore.

```
import UIKit

var pastData = [
    "What was the greatest achievement you accomplished the past five years?",
    "2",
    "3",
    "4",
    "5",
    "6",
    "7",
    "8",
    "9",
    "10",
]

var futureData = [
    "What is the single most important thing to have accomplished within the next five years?",
    "2",
    "3",
    "4",
    "5",
    "6",
    "7",
    "8",
    "9",
    "10",
]


class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


    @IBAction func pastButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }


    @IBAction func futureButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
}
```

I expect when pressing a button it changes the label text with one of the index' from a specific array.

I believe it is different from this thread, as my thread is about how to change the text when pressing a button and not every time it shows:
[How to randomize UILabel text each time the view controller is showed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43926546/how-to-randomize-uilabel-text-each-time-the-view-controller-is-showed)

[User Interface from Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrFFU.png)

Comment: And how do you decide which element from arrays should display on the label?

Comment: That's a very good question. I hope this answers your question. When pressing the Future button I would like it to choose a text randomly from the futureData array and the same thing goes for the past button / pastData array.

Comment: Like a lot of questions from newcomers to a language, this is actually 5 separate questions. They have been answered separately before, but there's no way for newcomers to make all these distinctions. The questions are: 1) How do I scope my variables so that class functions can see them? 2) How do I manage `@IBOutlet` naming to avoid runtime crashes? 3) How do I manipulate arrays, in particular selecting a random element 4) Where does the code go to handle user actions like button presses? 5) How do I visually manipulate simple views like `UILabel`s using my variables?

Answer (score 0):

To get random elements from an `array`, you need to simply call **`randomElement()`** method on that particular `array`, i.e.

```
@IBAction func pastButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.label.text = self.pastData.randomElement()
}


@IBAction func futureButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.label.text = self.futureData.randomElement()
}
```

In the above code,

1. I'm calling `pastData.randomElement()` when `pastButton` is pressed and
2. calling `futureData.randomElement()` when `futureButton` is pressed and

Comment: Thanks! I believe this will get me further.. Though I get the following error code now: "Value of type 'ViewController' has no member 'pastData'" I'm not sure what that means?

Comment: Check the name of your variable `pastData`. And if any variable with name `pastData` even exist in your viewController.

Comment: Thanks! I accidentally added my arrays below the "Import UIKit" line. I fixed the error by inserted the arrays below the "Class ViewController: UIViewController" line. Though now I'm getting an error now. Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Shamaz.ViewController 0x7f7ffa007420> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key pastButtonLayout.'

Comment: This exception means your outlets are not connected properly. Remove and add them again.

Comment: You are a genius. I hope I will become as skilled as you one day!

Comment: Sure. Do accept (tick on left) if it helped you. Happy coding..